# useQuery Breaking after useQuery by id apollo client

Tags: graphql, apollo-client

I have two queries one searches for all facilities with pagination another searches for facilityById.
In facilities i ask for some fields eg:
`

```
export const GET_FACILITIES = gql`
  query getFacilities(
    $after: String
    $order: [FacilityModelSortInput!]
    $where: FacilityModelFilterInput
    $first: Int
  ) {
    facilities(after: $after, order: $order, where: $where, first: $first) {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
        hasNextPage
        hasPreviousPage
        startCursor
      }

      edges {
        cursor
        node {
          timeStamp
          id
          latitude
          longitude
        }
      }
    }
  }`
```

`

when fetching  by facility id i want to expand on this facilities inner fields like so:

`

```
export const DETAIL_QUERY = gql`
  query detailQuery($id: ID!) {
    facilityById(id: $id) {
      id

     
      generadores {
        id
        
        capacity
        voltage
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

`

I know I could do separate query on backend to get these generators, but i want to get them like this. Problem is that the query by id is breaking the pagination on the multiple query. data from fetchMore becomes only the new fetched data and not all data on cache, i see the data on cache with apollo fierefox addon working fine, but returned data by useQuery is not, pageInfo is also only on start cursor of 15 items,  on cache is all items. I am using

relayStylePagination(),

works fine untill the byID query is executed.

I tried to work with pagination, fetching by id adding fields is breaking pagination.

Comment: I am pretty sure the byId query is updating the row on the facilities edges since they both correspond to the facilitymodel typename. This behaviour is breaking the facilities query pagination for some reason.

Comment: Best ways so far to fix the problem are:

Comment: a: ask for all deatails on main query

Comment: b: exclude asking for id in second query, in thiscase mutations will not automatically update your list.